# Updated vector elements do not print

Tags: c++, vector, stl

The code below is not printing the updated vector elements after replacing the elements that are less than the mean of the first and last element.

How may this code be improved upon, the user inputs array of specified length and replaces each element that is smaller than the mean of the first and last element with the mean.

Is there a better way to pass the vector to the function, or more efficient way to manage memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> getData()
{
    int n;
    std::vector<double> intputData;
    std::cout << "Enter array length\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Enter the numbers\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int tmpIn;
        std::cin >> tmpIn;
        intputData.push_back(tmpIn);
    }
    return intputData;
}


void modifyData(std::vector<double> &data_mo)
{
    double f=data_mo[0];
    double l=data_mo[data_mo.size() - 1];
    double av = (f + l)/2;
    for (auto j: data_mo)
    {
        if(j < av){
            j = av;
        }
    }
}

void printData(std::vector<double> &data_pr)
{
    for (auto i: data_pr)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(){

    std::vector<double> data_ma = getData();
    modifyData(data_ma);
    printData(data_ma);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`modifyData` needs it's range-based `for` loop to modify the elements by reference, otherwise your modifications are working on copies of the elements and not the elements themselves.

change

```
for (auto j: data_mo)
```

to

```
for (auto &j: data_mo)
```

Also, a simple improvement is to make `printData` take it's parameter by const reference because the vector does not get changed.

```
void printData(const std::vector<double> &data_pr)
```

Comment: I assumed passing inputData by reference to modifyData would be sufficient to properly update the elements, why is this not the case?

Comment: How you pass a parameter to a function, and how you use it _inside_ the function are two different things. Your usage of `auto` had the default [type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) of holding a copy of the element.

Comment: What would be the advantages of using std::span to pass the vector container to each function?

Comment: Furthermore, what’s the benefit of adding the const qualifier before auto in the range based for loop?

Comment: @DarnocEloc I see no advantages to using `std::span` here (when it becomes available), because it's not the intended usage of it, and it's clearer without with it. Do use `const` for the loop of `printData` and don't use it for `modifyData`. The former shouldn't modify the elements and the later is intentionally supposed to.